# What is required in order to claim a tax deduction for use of a motor vehicle?

Tags: tax-law, australia

I have a question about Commonwealth income tax law.

Suppose I am an employee at a retail chain. Occasionally, my boss asks me to take stock from one store to another. I use my private motor vehicle to do so. I pay for the petrol, repairs, etc out of my own pocket. The employer contributes nothing to my motor vehicle.

Under what conditions can I claim an income tax deduction for costs associated with my motor vehicle?

Comment: In the US, that's an unreimbused employee expense, and deductable.  No idea about Australia, nor other Commonwealth countries.

Answer (score 1):

In the circumstances you describe, you can claim the out of pocket expenses as a work related tax deduction, provided you owned or leased the vehicle. The ATO has [some information](https://www.ato.gov.au/Individuals/Tax-Return/2016/Tax-return/Deduction-questions-D1-D10/D1-Work-related-car-expenses-2016/) on work-related car expenses and if you don't own the vehicle, you may still be able to claim expenses as [travel expenses](https://www.ato.gov.au/Individuals/Tax-return/2016/Tax-return/Deduction-questions-D1-D10/D2-Work-related-travel-expenses-2016/).